# Create a custom exchange with RabbitMQ for filtering location

Tags: rabbitmq, filtering, publish-subscribe

I am trying to develop a game with a pub/sub mechanism, so for each client-map I have a Notify Update channel. The client must subscribe to that to receive updates. But this subscribe must be conditioned by player's Area Of Interest. This interest is given by a rectangle which is based on avatar coordinates.

I am also pretty new to the RabbitMq but I understand that the content-based filtering can be provided by the headers exchange. How can I build a custom exchange that will redirect the message to the specific queue or what other strategy/technology can I choose?